# Iterations in a Jacobian method function

Tags: c++

I'm making a function for doing the Jacobian Method.  My problem is that my iterations are supposed to let the x vector elements converge to 1s, however instead of 1s the x vector elements in my functions just become 'nan's ?

```
void Jacobi(int n, double (* A)[20], double * b, double * x) 
{
   double sum[20];
   double xnext[20];

   cout << "sum" << endl;
   for (int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++)
   {
       sum[i]=0;
       cout << sum[i]<<endl;
   }

   cout << endl;
   cout << endl;

   cout << "xnext" << endl;
   for (int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++)
   {
       xnext[i]=0;
       cout << xnext[i]<< endl; 
   }

   //iterations loop
   for (int iter = 0 ; iter < n ; iter++)
   {       
       for (int i = 0; i < 20 ; i++)
       {
           sum[i] = 0;

           for (int j = 0 ; j < 20 ; j++)
           {
           if (i != j)
               sum[i] = sum[i] + (A[i][j] * x[j]) ;
           }

           xnext[i] = (1/A[i][i])*(b[i]-sum[i]);

       }

       cout << endl;

       cout << "xnext "<< iter <<endl;
       for(int i= 0; i < 20 ; i++)
       {
           x[i]=xnext[i];
           cout << x[i]<< endl;
       }

   } 

   cout << endl;

   cout << "New x vector" << endl;
   for (int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++)
   {
      cout << x[i] << endl;
   }

   return;
}

int main() 
{
  //defining matrix A
  double A[20][20];    
  //defining vectors x and b
  double x[20];        
  double b[20];
  double sol[20];

  //for Matrix A
  //initialize everything to zero
  memset(A[0], 0, 20*20*sizeof(double));
  // set elements for main three diagonals
  for (int i = 0 ; i< 19; ++i)
  {
      A[i][i] = 2.0; 
      A[i][i+1] = -1.0; 
      A[i+1][i] = -1.0; 
   }
   // set last element
   A[19][19] = 2.0;

   //for vector x
   for (int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; ++i)
   {
       x[i]=0;
   }

   //for vector b
   for (int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++)
   {
       if (i=0)
          b[i]=1;
       else if (i=19)
          b[i]=1;
       else
          b[i]=0;
   }           


   //for vector solution
   for (int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++)
   {
       sol[i] = 1 ;
   }           

   double * ptr[20];
   for (int i= 0; i < 20 ; i++)
       ptr[i] = A[i];

   cout << "x vector" << endl;
   cout << endl;
   for (int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; ++i)
   {
       cout << x[i] << endl;
   }

   cout << endl;

   //using Gauss-Seidel Function
   Jacobi(40, A , b , x); 




   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is almost right, but there are some problems.

The matrix A is not initialized correctly.  The main diagonal is filled in with 2.0.  However, the code that fills the next closest diagonals with -1.0 goes out of bounds when i is 19.  Furthermore, none of the other elements of A are initialized.  This leads to the following changes:

```
// initialize everything to zero
memset(A[0], 0, 20*20*sizeof(double));
// set elements for main three diagonals
for (int i = 0 ; i< 19; ++i)
{
    A[i][i] = 2.0; 
    A[i][i+1] = -1.0; 
    A[i+1][i] = -1.0; 
}
// set last element
A[19][19] = 2.0;
```

The next change is to the Jacobi method itself. `xnext[i] = (1.0/A[i][i])*(b[i] - sum[i]);` is the correct formula for the next x.  However, the next line replaces `xnext` with the delta between the iterates.  After increasing the number of iterations to 600, the resulting vector ended up being pretty close to what Octave came up for a solution.

Comment: Okay.  So adjust matrix and  take out on the line about replacing xnext with delta.  My function is now returning values of actual numbers, but only a few of the elements are close to 1.  I'll keep fiddling with it I guess.

Comment: Why were you expecting all ones?  You had that the second element and the last element were one and all the rest were zero.  Now, if the first element and the last element were one, then the answer should be all ones.

Comment: That was a loop typo on my part.  I fixed it so that it is now looking for b[0] and b[19], which would be the first and last element entries.